# Bootstrap 3 on Android - Menu dropdown opens link instead of dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 on Wordpress, and trying to squeeze in an extra dropdown level.  I think I read that it only supports two levels by default.  I have it working on the desktop and on IOS devices, but on Android devices you can't get to the last drop down items because it opens their parent page instead.

[image: Android devices open Students instead of the menu below]

This is the site...
http://cslc2012.ca/

I've tried using something like this, but I don't really know javascript that well:

```
 <script>
 $('.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
 })
    </script>
```

I'm using the bootstrap navwalker for wordpress: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php

in the navwalker, it says:

```
    // If item has_children add atts to a.
            if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
                $atts['href']           = '#';
                $atts['data-toggle']    = 'dropdown';
                $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-toggle';
                $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
            } else {
                $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
            }
```

You'd think this would do it... the depth isn't 0...  and it's resetting the other links to #

Thanks

Comment: I was able to remove the link (via WordPress admin, add the top level item as a link and then remove the link but the leave the menu item), but the dropdown menu opens and then the whole menu closes before you can get to it...

Comment: Could I modify this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519875/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-when-mouse-is-out to keep the menu open when the parent item is touched?